# Initial Fastapi request is not being processed and stays on hold

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, fastapi

I have a worker fastapi. This api basically creates worker functions and then some data will be processed. My problem arises at the start of these workers. When I first try to make a request, the request stays on hold forever. It doesn't reach the api. When I cancel the request and make another one, everything works perfectly, my workers start.

This is the endpoint which I'm using to create workers:

```
@app.get("/connectors")
async def start_process(conf: Union[Connector, None] = None):
    print(conf)
    conf_list = conf.config[0]
 
    if not conf_list:
        return {"message": "Empty configuration list"}
    # os.environ.update({str(i[0]): i[1] for i in conf_list})
    log.info(f"Cassandra Host: {conf_list.cassandra_host}, Type: {type(conf_list.cassandra_host)}")

    globalConfig.set(conf_list.cassandra_host,
            conf_list.cassandra_port,
            conf_list.cassandra_keyspace,
            conf_list.kafka_bootstrap_server,
            conf_list.topic)
    # Check if the process with the same name already exists
    existing_process = next((p for p in processes if p["name"] == conf.name), None)
    if existing_process:
        return {"message": "Connector is not created. Duplicated error."}
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=main, args=(len(processes) + 1,conf_list.connector_class,globalConfig,))
    p.start()
    processes.append({"p": p, "name": conf.name})
    return {"message": f"Started process with ID {p.pid} or {conf.name}"}
```

This is the body I'm sending to the api:

```
{
    "name":"cassandra-sink-dog1",
    "config":[
        {
        "connector_class":"io.inovasyon.connect.cassandra.ShardedSinkConnector",
        "cassandra_host":"192.168.2.165",
        "cassandra_port":"9042",
        "cassandra_keyspace":"orion_dog",
        "kafka_bootstrap_server":"192.168.2.165:29092",
        "topic":"eys.orion-dog.entities"
        }
    ]
}
```

Why is my first request being blocked and I need to cancel it and retry it for it to work?

Edit 1: The entrypoint shown below;

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import multiprocessing
from config.Config import Config 
from typing import List,Union
from pydantic import BaseModel
from functions.workerReplication import ReplicationSinkConnector
from functions.workerShard import KafkaConsumerSinkConnector
from functions.workerLogstash import KafkaConsumerLogstashConnector
import logging
import coloredlogs
import uvicorn
from termcolor import colored
coloredlogs.install(level="INFO")
log = logging.getLogger("Functions")

app = FastAPI()
processes = []
globalConfig = Config()
class ConnectorConf(BaseModel):
    connector_class: str
    cassandra_port: str
    cassandra_host: str
    cassandra_keyspace: str
    kafka_bootstrap_server: str
    topic: str

class Connector(BaseModel):
    name: str
    config: List[ConnectorConf]

def main(num,classType,globalConfig):
    """A function that simulates a process"""
    log.info(colored("Worker: ","blue")+ "{}".format(num) + colored(" Running","green"))
    if "ShardedSinkConnector" in str(classType):
        log.info(colored("ShardedSinkConnector: ","green")+ colored(" started.","green"))
        KafkaConsumerSinkConnector().workerKafkaShard(globalConfig)
    if "ReplicationSinkConnector" in str(classType):
        log.info(colored("ReplicationSinkConnector: ","green")+ colored(" started.","green"))
        ReplicationSinkConnector.workerCassandraReplication(globalConfig)
    if "LogstashSinkConnector" in str(classType):
        log.info(colored("LogstashSinkConnector: ","green")+ colored(" started.","green"))
        KafkaConsumerLogstashConnector.workerKafkaLogstash(globalConfig,classType)

@app.get("/connectors")
async def start_process(conf: Union[Connector, None] = None):
    conf_list = conf.config[0]
    # os.environ.update({str(i[0]): i[1] for i in conf_list})
    log.info(f"Cassandra Host: {conf_list.cassandra_host}, Type: {type(conf_list.cassandra_host)}")
    globalConfig.set(conf_list.cassandra_host,
            conf_list.cassandra_port,
            conf_list.cassandra_keyspace,
            conf_list.kafka_bootstrap_server,
            conf_list.topic)
    # Check if the process with the same name already exists
    existing_process = next((p for p in processes if p["name"] == conf.name), None)
    if existing_process:
        return {"message": "Connector is not created. Duplicated error."}
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=main, args=(len(processes) + 1,conf_list.connector_class,globalConfig,))
    p.start()
    processes.append({"p": p, "name": conf.name})
    return {"message": f"Started process with ID {p.pid} or {conf.name}"}


@app.get("/connectors/{name}")
async def stop_process(name: Union[str, None] = None):
    for idx, p in enumerate(processes):
        if p["name"] == name:
            print(p["p"])
            process_id = p["p"].pid
            p = p["p"]
            p.terminate()
            processes.pop(idx)
            log.info(f"Stopped process with ID: {process_id} - {name} Stopped")
            # log.info(colored("message: Stopped process with ID ","blue")+ "{}".format(id)+ "\n{}".format(name) + colored(" Stopped","red"))
    return {"message": f"Process with ID {id} not found"}


# if __name__ == "__main__":
#     uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
# python -m uvicorn CassandraBackend:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload
```

Comment: I think there is not enough code to help you.
Try starting from empty endpoint and add code line by line. What line of code causes problem you mentioned?

Comment: Does your middlewares modify the starlette's Request object by any means? This includes reading any unreversable buffers like the request.Body. I am going to sleep, hope you will understand it as we both are in same time zones, I will look into your entire middleware setup if you share them when I wake up.

Comment: So check anything executing before your endpoint and share them with me, as your endpoint doesn't do anything to block the main thread.

Comment: @Caner-sagopaninsagkolu this particular service doesn't have any middleware I'm aware of actually. So I don't think anything being executed.

Comment: First of all, why both functions are GET? Changing method of endpoint /connectors from GET to PUT yields no error. I even get the error `{
  "message": "Connector is not created. Duplicated error."
}` After executing the /connectors twice with the same body, so I see no error besides your special logged error. Only difference from your code is, I deleted any internal functions you are declaring. Like this connectors `ReplicationSinkConnector`. Please check if connectors block anything.

Comment: @Caner-sagopaninsagkolu Well they've declared the methods like that and I didn't change it. I explicitly set breakpoints above the internal functions and first requests aren't being captured by them. After I cancel and remake the request, It gets 307 and then worker starts successfully. We're suspecting on multiprocessing. Also when I change `conf` model to the plain dict, first request is being successfull and the second one is staying on hold.

Comment: @rumeysayuk Try dropping the multiprocess with https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/. Maybe https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/611 can solve your issue.

Comment: @Caner-sagopaninsagkolu we'll try that tomorrow. Sagolasin.

Comment: Ricalar. After ditching multiprocess, if you still cannot make it work, set a timeout on all requests https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#timeout and profile the app https://pyinstrument.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#profile-a-web-request-in-fastapi. After request is hanging up, wait for it to timeout, then analyze the profile data to see where it actually hangs (or you can just send the profile html to me). But I believe ditching multiprocess would be enough.